# How to configure a backout queue for an mq?

Tags: ibm-mq

I have to configure a backout queue for the MQ input node in my application.I created one local queue as a backout queue, but don't know how to assign it.Also, how to check the backout threshold and direct the message to backout queue if the count exceeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RUNMQSC run the following

```
ALTER QL(<Q1>) BOQNAME(<BACKQ>) BOTHRESH(<number>)
```

For example the following sets backout queue BACKQ with a threshold of 5.

```
ALTER QL(MAINQ) BOQNAME(BACKQ) BOTHRESH(5)
```